# Android library to work with local maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app which uses a library of my own. I am developing them at the same time so when I have a change in my library I want to test it in my app as well.

They are setup as different projects since my library will also be used by other developers. The way we work is we build the library using a CI platform adn deploy it to an artifactory server.

Then from the app I reference this library directly through artifactory. This way when my CI platform builds the app, the build process takes the lib from artifactory and CI works smoothly.

This is a good way to work but is a pain in the ass when developing them in parallel, because I have to commit the changes, create a pull request, merge it with the development branch and wait for CI to build it and deploy it on the artifactory server, just so I can test it on the app.

Coming from java EE development, I used maven install, which deploys the artifact in the local maven repo, then I could already use it from my web application.

I want to do soemthing similar, i.e. have gradle deploy my artifact on my local repo, so the artifact on the local repo is updated but not on the remote one. This way I can debug more easily while still keeping the CI setup in place.

But I have no idea how to do this on gradle. The artifactory plugin seems like it only allows deployment on an artifactory server.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the maven plugin, you can run the install task to deploy the artifacts to your local Maven repo [1]. After you have the Artifacts deployed to your local maven repo, you need to add `mavenLocal()` [2] as one of the repositories to be able to resolve the dependency. One strategy I use is to always set a custom version for my local copy so that I can be certain that the local version is getting picked up - but if you choose not to do that the dependencies get resolved in the order the repositories are listed (so you'll need to ensure mavenLocal is before your Artifactory server).

[1] https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html, https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

[2] https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-maven-local-repository-for-gradle-build/2244